# Problema acessando elemento do array

Tags: c, array

Estou com um problema na função abaixo que trunca todas as palavras de forma a terem no máximo N carateres.

Por exemplo: se a *string* contiver : "liberdade, igualdade e fraternidade" , a    invocação de `truncW(t,4)` deve dar "libe igua e frat".

Isto foi o que consegui:

```
void truncW (char t[], int n)
{
  int j ;

   for ( j = 0 ; j < n ; j++)      
   {
    if ( isspace (t[j]) == 0 )
    { printf ("%c " , t[j]);}
   }
}

void main ()
{
   char t[] = "liberdade, igualdade e fraternidade";
   truncW (t,4);
}
```

O *output* dá apenas : "libe"

Queria saber como faço **para percorrer toda a lista e tirar no máximo n caracteres de cada palavra** . O que falta no código para permitir isso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O seu maior problema está aqui:

```c
for ( j = 0 ; j < n ; j++)
```

Isso significa que você só vai percorrer os primeiros `n` caracteres da string, e não de cada palavra.

Acho que a melhor forma de fazer isso é tendo um contador para contar quantas letras em uma palavra você já viu, e zerá-lo sempre que encontrar o espaço. Você usa o valor do contador para decidir se imprime a letra ou não.

Fiz assim e funcionou:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

void truncW(char t[], int n)
{
    int len = strlen(t);
    int j;
    int letras_consecutivas = 0;

    for (j = 0; j < len; j++)   
    {
        if (isspace(t[j]) == 0)
        {
            letras_consecutivas++;
        } else {
            letras_consecutivas = 0;
        }
        if (letras_consecutivas <= n) {
            printf("%c", t[j]);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char t[] = "liberdade, igualdade e fraternidade";
    truncW(t, 4);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Falta você continuar percorrendo a string até encontrar outro espaço (ou o fim da string) e - se achou um espaço - começar tudo de novo. Em vez de fazer o laço de `0` a `n`, faça de `0` ao fim da string, e use uma contagem separada para ir de `0` a `n` (resetando essa contagem toda vez que achar um espaço):

```
int j;
int contagem = 0; // Quantas letras você já tirou da palavra

for ( j = 0 ; j < strlen(t) ; j++ ) // Percorre a string inteira, não só os n primeiros
{
    if ( isspace (t[j]) == 0 && contagem < n ) // Se é letra e ainda não tirou tudo
    { 
        printf ("%c " , t[j]); // Tira
        contagem++;            // E incrementa a contagem
    }
    else if ( isspace (t[j]) != 0 ) // Se é espaço
        contagem = 0;               // Reseta a contagem, pra consumir outra palavra
}
```

**Nota:** esse exemplo imprime só as letras tiradas das palavras, não os espaços entre elas (i.e. a saída será `libeiguaefrat`). Se quer imprimir também os espaços, veja [a resposta do Victor Stafusa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/54436/215).

Answer (score 4):

Você não estava varrendo toda a *string* e ainda não estava reiniciando a contagem dos caracteres limite de cada palavra. Eu faria assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

void truncW (char t[], int n) {
    int s = strlen(t); //acha o tamanho da string
    //cria dois contadores aqui, o i que varre **toda** a string e o j que vai até n
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < s; i++, j++) {
        if (isspace(t[i]) > 0) { //se achou um espaço em branco
            j = -1; //reseta o contador de caracteres já que vai começar outra palavra
            printf(" "); //dá um espaço
        } else if (j < n) { //se ainda não atingiu o limite de caracteres por palavra
            printf("%c", t[i]); //imprime o caractere
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
   char t[] = "liberdade, igualdade e fraternidade";
   truncW(t, 4);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/S3z4X7). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/szsnsidf-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/RemoveChars.c).

Note que o `e` aparece, se não pode aparecer deve ter uma regra clara sobre isto.

Comment: `if (isspace(t[i]) > 0) /* ... */;` ??? Não há impedimento para o `isspace()` devolver um número negativo para indicar *true*.

Answer (score 3):

Usando **flex** (o flex gera C e é optimo para programar processamento textual) :

```
%option noyywrap

%%
[a-z]{4,}     { yyleng=4 ; ECHO; }   
.|\n          {            ECHO; }   // (desnecessário: ação default)

%%
int main(){ yylex(); return 0;}
```

Modo de utilização:

```
flex -o trunca.c trun.fl 
cc   -o trunca   trunca.c
echo "liberdade, igualdade e fraternidade" | trunca
```

dá o esperado:

```
libe, igua e frat
```